# How to get backslash working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xmodmap, xkb

I've been using `.Xmodmap` to configure my custom keymap.

I know that Ubuntu uses `xkb`, but `xkb` seems to be very complex (inheritance and lots of files to configure something).

I've managed to get all keys to work through `.Xmodmap`, except for the backslash. I really have no clue if some rules of xkb overwrite the backslash somehow.

I'd like backslash to be `Alt + keycode 49`

I've added the following rule in `.Xmodmap`

```
keycode 49 = less greater backslash backslash backslash
```

However, the backslash is not generated. I guess it might be overridden by `xkb` somehow. Do you have an idea how I could get it to work? Respectively, where I might have to do some changes in `xkb`?

Here's what I get if I run: `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10`

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     ch,us
variant:    de_mac,
options:    caps:swapescape
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+ch(de_mac)+us:2+inet(evdev)+capslock(swapescape)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+ch(de_mac)+us:2+inet(evdev)+capslock(swapescape)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I have a similar problem!

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The way would be to use xkb. But it's (a bit) too complex. I'd rather buy another keyboard and save some time :(